# Nakagawa's R2 for a two-level model with two weight variables

Tags: multilevel-analysis, r-squared

I am trying to get Nakagawa's conditional R2 in R, for a two level model with two weight variables. The problem I am facing is however that only a limited amount of packages allows to estimate twolevel models with two weight variables. To my knowledge EdSurvey and WeMix allow for this. When I estimate models with these packages, the statements that can be used to get Nakagawa's R2 do not work.
Does anyone knows a package that does work, or knows a way around this problem?

Many thanks in advance.

Kind regards,

Emilie Franck